# Anomaly in summing two byte variables in Java

Tags: java, operators, primitive

Please check the following peices:

```
byte a=1, b=2;  b+=a;
```

is perfectly legal.
While,

```
byte a=1, b=2;  b=b+a;
```

is not allowed. Although both of these are considered equivalent.
Is there any difference in the mechanism of the two ways of assignment?

Comment: @DaveNewton oh no, I looked it up in the spec, but had better looked it up on SO ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.26.2):

> A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent to E1 = (T)((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1 is evaluated only once.

This means that `b+=a` is equivalent to `(byte)(a+b)`, instead of simply `a+b`. The latter still needs a cast to `byte`.